# Java SQL Table names with Special characters

Tags: java, mysql, apache-commons-dbutils

I have a code, which creates tables on the fly. These tables are used to store and get data for different processes.

Problem: Table names are being created with special characters like "&" and others. MySQL Allows table names with special characters. Not an issue with MySQL.

When i use DBUtils to query data from such table, i get an exception at the special character. 
If i were using regular jdbc, then i could have escaped those and could have processed data. But DButils not allowing to escape such characters.

I tried adding double quotes to table name and tried processing, however the problem still exists. Any advice??

```
java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near '-AO_I   ( Datetime,  L, ' at line 1 
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.AbstractQueryRunner.rethrow(AbstractQueryRunner.java:392)
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.update(QueryRunner.java:491)
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.update(QueryRunner.java:404)
```

Removing all column names and detailed table name. 
The table name is "NRI-AO_I"
The code adds data to hundreds of tables, but fails for few. these table names have special character in table name. Tables having "&" or "-" in their name fail.

Comment: Can you please provide us some code or example where you are getting error? What is the exception that you are getting?

Comment: So your problem is specific to querying with "DBUtils"? Do you mean [Apache Commons DBUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/) or something else?

Comment: Its Apache DBUtils. The problem is with only few tables.

Comment: Can you share the code that's actually throwing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to use special characters in table names but if you have no other alternatives, Quote your ambiguous or "special" table names with a back tick.
e.g:

```
select * from `NRI-AO_I`
```